# Eclipse; encapsuling a block of methods

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

Good morning to everyone.

The simple question I have is:

Is there any way of joining blocks of methods?

For example: If I have all the getters and setters, can I minimize all of them in only one line of code?

Thanks!

Comment: do you want to minify ?

Comment: In the world of Java its actually referred to as an obfuscator  take a look at http://proguard.sourceforge.net/

Comment: For setters/getters you could use https://projectlombok.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly build JavaBeans without getters and setters. The BeanCustomizer, BeanInfo, and BeanDescriptor classes. Here is an example; from this:

```
private int property;
public int getProperty  (         ){ return property; }
public void setProperty (int value}{ property = value; }
```

You'll be able to use something like:

```
private @property int property;
```

Hope you find it useful.